# Getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY statement without any aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle, case, exists

I have a huge `CASE` statement in my query which works fine except one part.

When I add the `EXISTS` clause in one of the `WHEN` clauses I get **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY statement**. I can't figure out why since there are no aggregate functions inside the `SELECT`. If I comment the whole `EXISTS` part or all the `LEFT JOIN`s inside it (and the last two conditions in `WHERE`) the query works fine so I assume the problem is with the joins.

I'm pretty sure I use all the needed columns for join, but even if I didn't, how multiple return rows should affect the result of `EXISTS`? It just checks if 0 or more rows are returned, as far as I know.

There is a `GROUP BY` statement in the query though, but I just copy the whole `CASE` thing there and it works if I comment out the `EXISTS` clause.

I can't post the whole code because it's 500 lines, hope this is enough:

```
WHEN NVL(BH_LAST_WEEK.QTY,0) < NVL(BH_PREV_WEEK.QTY,0)
 AND F.TOTFCST > F.TOTHIST
 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM SCPOMGR.DFUVIEW DV_INNER
             INNER JOIN SCPOMGR.ITEM I_INNER
                     ON I_INNER.ITEM = DV_INNER.DMDUNIT
             LEFT JOIN BASEHIST BH_LAST_WEEK_INNER
                    ON BH_LAST_WEEK_INNER.DMDUNIT = DV_INNER.DMDUNIT
                   AND BH_LAST_WEEK_INNER.LOC = DV_INNER.LOC
                   AND BH_LAST_WEEK_INNER.STARTDATE = F.STARTDATE
             LEFT JOIN BASEHIST BH_PREV_WEEK_INNER
                    ON BH_PREV_WEEK_INNER.DMDUNIT = DV_INNER.DMDUNIT
                   AND BH_PREV_WEEK_INNER.LOC = DV_INNER.LOC
                   AND BH_PREV_WEEK_INNER.STARTDATE = F.STARTDATE - 7
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                        FROM EFF_PRICES 
                        WHERE STARTDATE = F.STARTDATE) EP_LAST_WEEK_INNER
                    ON EP_LAST_WEEK_INNER.DMDUNIT = DV_INNER.DMDUNIT
                   AND EP_LAST_WEEK_INNER.LOC = DV_INNER.LOC
             LEFT JOIN EFF_PRICES EP_PREV_WEEK_INNER
                    ON EP_PREV_WEEK_INNER.DMDUNIT = DV_INNER.DMDUNIT
                   AND EP_PREV_WEEK_INNER.LOC = DV_INNER.LOC
                   AND EP_PREV_WEEK_INNER.STARTDATE = F.STARTDATE - 7
             WHERE I_INNER.U_HL4_CODE = I.U_HL4_CODE
               AND DV_INNER.LOC = F.LOC
               AND DV_INNER.DMDGROUP = 'RETAIL'
               AND DV_INNER.U_LEVEL = '000'
               AND EP_LAST_WEEK_INNER.EFFPRICE / EP_PREV_WEEK_INNER.EFFPRICE < 0.75
               AND BH_LAST_WEEK_INNER.QTY > BH_PREV_WEEK_INNER.QTY * (1 + 0.6 * F.TOTHIST / F.TOTFCST)
              )
```

Comment: Any chance you have a column from the outer target tables within the subselect, which isn't in the `GROUP BY` of the outer query?

Comment: Well, yes, for example `F.STARTDATE - 7` is not in the outer `GROUP BY`. But it's not in the output so I didn't think this could cause the trouble...

Comment: But you case is in the outer `WHERE` or in the list of selected columns of the outer query, isn't it? You cannot use any column of the outer query there, that isn't either part of the `GROUP BY` or passed to an aggregation function. This also applies for using them in correlated subqueries in that place, the DBMS can't figure out which value to choose from possibly many there too.

Comment: @stickybit . . . You should put your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said, you have a column `F.STARTDATE` in the subselect, which is a column of one of the target tables of the outer `FROM` (including any `JOIN`ed tables). Your `CASE` is in the outer `WHERE` or in the list of columns after the outer `SELECT`.

In the `WHERE` or the list of columns after `SELECT` of an outer (or standalone) query you cannot use any column, that isn't either part of the `GROUP BY` or passed to an aggregation function (if there is any `GROUP BY` of course). This also applies for using them in correlated subqueries in these aforementioned places. The DBMS can't figure out which value to choose from possibly many there too.

Comment: Well I thought that at first the `CASE` was calculated for each row and only then the values were grouped. At least this makes sense.